# ¿Cómo puedo traer de mysql los registros que le pido?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una app marketplace, donde cada usuario realiza una o mas publicaciones. Dentro del panel de usuario, hay un datatable donde necesito que aparezcan las publicaciónes de dicho usuario.

Este es mi consulta desde ajax al modelo que genera el json para el datatable

```
    <?php

require_once "../controladores/productos.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/productos.modelo.php";




class TablaProductos{

    

  /*=============================================
  MOSTRAR LA TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
  =============================================*/ 

  public function mostrarTablaProductos(){  



    $item = "14";
    
    $valor = "id_usuario";

    
    $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos2($item, $valor);


    

    $datosJson = '

        {   
            "data":[';

        for($i = 0; $i < count($productos); $i++){

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS CATEGORÍAS
            =============================================*/

            $item = "id";
            $valor = $productos[$i]["id_categoria"];

            $categorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

            if($categorias["categoria"] == ""){

                $categoria = "SIN CATEGORÍA";
            
            }else{

                $categoria = $categorias["categoria"];
            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS SUBCATEGORÍAS
            =============================================*/

            $item2 = "id";
            $valor2 = $productos[$i]["id_subcategoria"];

            $subcategorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item2, $valor2);

            if($subcategorias[0]["subcategoria"] == ""){

                $subcategoria = "SIN SUBCATEGORÍA";
            
            }else{

                $subcategoria = $subcategorias[0]["subcategoria"];
            }

            /*=============================================
            AGREGAR ETIQUETAS DE ESTADO
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["estado"] == 0){

                $colorEstado = "btn-danger";
                $textoEstado = "Desactivado";
                $estadoProducto = 1;

            }else{

                $colorEstado = "btn-success";
                $textoEstado = "Activado";
                $estadoProducto = 0;

            }

            $estado = "<button class='btn btn-xs btnActivar ".$colorEstado."' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' estadoProducto='".$estadoProducto."'>".$textoEstado."</button>";


            

            /*=============================================
            TRAER PRECIO
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["precio"] == 0){

                $precio = "Gratis";
            
            }else{

                $precio = "$ ".number_format($productos[$i]["precio"],2);

            }

            

            
            

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS ACCIONES
            =============================================*/

            $acciones = "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarProducto'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>";

            /*=============================================
            CONSTRUIR LOS DATOS JSON
            =============================================*/


            $datosJson .='[
                    
                    "'.($i+1).'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["titulo"].'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["id_usuario"].'",
                    "'.$categoria.'",
                    "'.$subcategoria.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["ruta"].'",
                    "'.$estado.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["tipo"].'",
                    "'.$precio.'",          
                    "'.$acciones.'"    

            ],';

        }

        $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);

        $datosJson .= ']

        }';
        


        echo $datosJson;

  }


}

/*=============================================
ACTIVAR TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
=============================================*/ 
$activarProductos = new TablaProductos();
$activarProductos -> mostrarTablaProductos();
```

Este es mi metodo en el modelo que hace la consulta

```
/*
    MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarProductos2($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE id_usuario = :$item");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY id DESC");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;


    }
```

Hasta ahora todo bien si yo mando  $item = null; porque manda todos los item de la tabla correctamente, ahora cuando a $item = "14" para probar (14 es el id del usuario) me trae todas las publicaciones excepto las que son del usuario en cuestión.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Tienes una errata en la consulta SQL. Es `SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE id_usuario = :item`, sin el símbolo `$` delante del nombre del marcador. Además, ¿en qué parte del código llamas a `mdlMostrarProductos2()`? Por último, `$datosJson` está mal generado. Deberías usar `json_encode()` en lugar de concatenar el contenido de variables a una cadena de caracteres.

Comment: Gracias por responder, hice el cambio que sugeriste. Ahora tengo otro error jeje

Comment: Gracias por responder, hice el cambio que sugeriste. Ahora tengo otro error jeje

Comment: ´Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\modo-desarrollo\frontend\modelos\productos.modelo.php:286´

Comment: @OscarGarcia ahora veo de actualizarte la parte del controlador donde invoca a **mdlMostrarProductos2()**

Comment: `static public function ctrMostrarProductos2($item1, $valor1){

  $tabla = "productos";

  $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductos2($tabla, $item1, $valor1);

  return $respuesta;
 
 }`

Comment: Me explicarías el error que tengo generando el json de esa manera? Me devuelve los datos correctamente si no tratara de mandar un item en especial, así como está el codigo. Si yo quisiera mandar en **ajax** la variable **$item=null;** al método **ctrMostrarProductos2()** devuelve un json correcto de acuerdo a lo que le pido. Ahora con **$item="14";** se rompe, despues de tu sugerencia

Comment: Es porque la siguiente instrucción quizá esté mail: `bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);`, pidiendo ser `bindParam(":item", $item, PDO::PARAM_STR);`. Te pregunté cómo llamabas a la función para entender el uso de `$item` y `$value`, ya que no tienen sentido a no ser que sea para un `:$item = :value` en el `WHERE`.